# Material-table render function in columns doesn't work properly

Tags: reactjs, material-table

Good afternoon.

I am currently facing a problem for some days already. I am using mbrn material-table for React and i need to use some customization in some columns. For that, i am using the render function inside each column definition. The problem is that whenever i use the render, the pagination stops working. If i try to change the number of rows to show in the table from 10 to 20 for example, it remains always in 10. But if i remove the render function it works well.

I would really appreciate some help.

```
<Col className="px-3" style={{height: "88%", padding: "1% 0%", maxHeight: "88%", display: "flex", alignItems: "center"}}>
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={themeTable}>
       <MaterialTable
           style={{width: "100%", maxHeight: "100%"}}
           tableRef={tableRef}
           icons={{
              Search: () => <Search />,
              Check: () => <Check />,
              DetailPanel: () => <ChevronRight />,
              Export: () => <SaveAlt />,
              Filter: React.forwardRef((props, ref) => <SearchIcon ref={ref} />),
              FirstPage: () => <FirstPage />,
              LastPage: () => <LastPage />,
              NextPage: () => <ChevronRight />,
              PreviousPage: () => <ChevronLeft />,
              SortArrow: forwardRef((props, ref) => <ArrowUpwardIcon{...props} ref={ref}/>),
                                ThirdStateCheck: () => <Remove />,
                                ViewColumn: () => <ViewColumn />,
           }}
           columns={[
              { title: '', field: 'OrderStatus', cellStyle, render: () => <span>abc</span>},
              { title: 'Tp. Doc.', field: 'DocType', filterPlaceholder: "Tp. Doc.", cellStyle},
              { title: 'Nº. Doc.', field: 'OrderID', filterPlaceholder: "Nº. Doc.", cellStyle},
              { title: 'Doc. Cliente', field: 'RequesterID', filterPlaceholder: "Doc. Cliente", cellStyle},
              { title: 'Cód. Cliente', field: 'ClientID', filterPlaceholder: "Cód. Cliente", cellStyle},
              { title: 'Cliente', field: 'PartnerName', filterPlaceholder: 'Cliente', cellStyle},
              { title: 'Qtd.', field: 'QtyOrd', filterPlaceholder: 'Qtd.', cellStyle},
              { title: 'Qtd. Satisf.', field: 'QtySatisf', filterPlaceholder: 'Qtd. Satisf.', cellStyle},
              { title: 'Data Doc.', field: 'CreationDateTime', filterPlaceholder: 'Data Doc.', cellStyle},
              { title: 'Data Prev. Entrega', field: 'OrderDatePrev', filterPlaceholder: 'Data Prev. Entrega', cellStyle},
              { title: 'Estado', field: 'DocStatusDescr', filterPlaceholder: 'Estado', cellStyle},
              { title: 'Nome Entrega', field: 'DeliveryPartnerName', filterPlaceholder: 'Nome Entrega', cellStyle},
              { title: 'Endereço Entrega', field: 'Address', filterPlaceholder: 'Endereço Entrega', cellStyle},
              { title: 'Cód. Postal', field: 'PostalCode', filterPlaceholder: 'Cód. Postal', cellStyle},
              { title: 'Cidade', field: 'City', filterPlaceholder: 'Cidade', cellStyle},
              { title: 'País', field: 'Country', filterPlaceholder: 'País', cellStyle},
              { title: 'Cód. Barras Doc.', field: 'BarCode', filterPlaceholder: 'Cód. Barras Doc.', cellStyle},
              { title: 'Track. Number', field: 'TrackingNumber', filterPlaceholder: 'Track. Number', cellStyle},
              { title: 'Doc. Origem', field: 'DocOri', filterPlaceholder: 'Doc. Origem', cellStyle},
              { title: 'Utilizador Modif.', field: 'ModifUser', filterPlaceholder: 'Utilizador Modif.', cellStyle},
              { title: 'Data Modif.', field: 'ModifDateTime', filterPlaceholder: 'Data Modif.', cellStyle}                                ]}
           data={query =>
               new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                  let url = `${config.appUrl}/orderController/getOrders?` + buildTableQueryString(query) 
                        + '&checkboxFilter=' + encodeURIComponent(this.getCheckboxFilters(this.state.pendentChecked, this.state.completedChecked));
                        
                  fetch(url)
                      .then(response => response.json())
                      .then(result => {
                         console.log("Result: ", query);
                         resolve({
                                
                           data: result.data,
                           page: result.page - 1,
                           totalCount: result.totalCount,
                         });
                       })
                   })
              }
              options={{
                 filtering: true,
                 search: false,
                 toolbar: false,
                 headerStyle: {
                 fontSize: 13,
                 whiteSpace: "nowrap",
                 padding: 10,
                 backgroundColor: "#24649C",
                 color: "white"
              },
              pageSize: 10,
              //overflowY: "scroll",
              //maxBodyHeight: "calc(100vh - 60px)"
            }}
            onRowClick={this.handleRowClick}
            components={{
                Cell: props => (
                   <MTableCell {...props} style={{padding: 11}} />
                ),
                Header: props => (
                   <MTableHeader {...props} style={{padding: 11}} />
                ),
                Row: props => (
                   <MTableBodyRow {...props} style={{padding: 11}} />
                ),
                Body: props => (
                   <MTableBody {...props} style={{padding: 11}} />
                )
            }}
      />
  </MuiThemeProvider>
```

Comment: Please, don't use screenshots of your code when you can paste it here.

Comment: I have edited the post. But i would like some help, if you can...

Comment: Could you post the entire code of your material-table component?

Comment: @NicoE i have done it.